# Extend Image Provider

Tags: android, flutter

i am using this extended Image to crop images from then Save the raw file to phone, get the raw data and push it to firebase storage. but i keep getting this error.

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:extended_image_library/src/extended_image_provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 34 pos 12: 'cacheRawData': you should set [ExtendedImageProvider.cacheRawData] to true, if you want to get rawImageData from provider.
```

Comment: add the code which is causing this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.